# Verification using Python Discord

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, roles, verification

I'm making a bot with python and I need help with two things.

1. Making a welcome message for users that include mentioning the user and mentioning the channel
2. Making a command that will remove the role "Unverified" and add 4 other roles. I also need it to send a message in the verification channel to make sure the person has been verified and send an embed in general chat telling the user to get self roles.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Before asking your question, have you done any research or have you came up with any code? This website is more about helping developpers with their code, your question have multiple questions in one and needs more focus ^^ Here's a useful link that might help you [asking better question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Well you could try

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".")

confirmEmoji = '\U00002705'    

@client.event()
async def on_ready():
    print("[Status] Ready")

@client.event()
async def on_member_join(ctx, member):
    channel = get(ctx.guild.channels,name="Welcome")
    await channel.send(f"{member.mention} has joined")

@client.command()
async def ConfirmMessage(ctx):
    global confirmEmoji
    message = await ctx.send("Confirm")
    await message.add_reaction(emoji=confirmEmoji)
    def check(reaction, user):
        if reaction.emoji == confirmEmoji:
            return True
        else: 
            return False
    while True:
        try:
            reaction, user = await client.wait_for("reaction_add", check=check, timeout=10)
        roleToRemove = get(ctx.guild.roles,name="unverified")
        memberToRemoveRole = get(ctx.guild.members,name=user.display_name)
        await memberToRemoveRole.remove_roles(roleToRemove)
```

Now all you have to do is go to the channel and enter .ConfirmMessage